# How best to model day time dependet activity?

Tags: r, regression, circular-statistics

I aquired the median activity data of animals per hour and wanted to model them dependent on time. Now I have tried different models and came up with the following. (This only includes a small portion of the whole data)

```
data <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
median_activity = c(27, 27.5, 37, 0, 0, 34, 92.5, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 7.5, 0, 3, 14, 31, 17, 30.5, 0, 0, 24.5, 15.5, 
    63, 4.5, 0, 4.5, 41, 3.5, 0, 13.5, 0, 0, 0, 18.5, 0, 0, 16.5, 
    0, 14, 20.5, 21.5, 2.5, 0, 25, 0, 36, 46.5, 11, 0, 13, 78.5, 
    2.5, 0, 11, 0, 0, 6.5, 0, 0, 98.5, 0, 12.5, 32.5, 0, 80, 
    11, 0, 52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 6.5, 0, 16.5, 43.5, 3.5, 
    37, 22, 2.5, 89, 10, 0, 48.5, 46, 20.5, 0, 9.5, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 12, 21.5, 3, 15, 59.5, 4.5, 42.5, 
    6.5, 0, 0, 40, 38.5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 39.5, 82, 5, 
    68, 5, 64, 25, 1, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 77, 0, 0, 35, 21, 55, 22, 
    90, 70.5, 63.5, 1.5, 32.5, 58, 25, 6.5, 16.5, 51.5, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 17.5, 0, 0, 56.5, 42, 2, 0, 20, 82.5, 
    22, 2, 0, 5, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 0, 0, 188.5, 16, 5, 
    372, 177, 157.5, 0, 22, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 101.5, 0, 0, 
    9, 16.5, 124.5, 82, 79, 64.5, 95, 0, 7, 98, 0, 62, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2.5, 0, 0, 0, 85, 51, 72, 1, 60.5,
    36.5, 0, 59, 106, 0, 0, 4, 0, 12, 0, 1.5, 0, 2, 0, 2), 
time_mdl = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L)), class = "data.frame")
act.mdl<-lm(median_activity ~ group*cos(2*pi*time_mdl/24),data=data)
```

Which performs much better than the standard

```
act.mdl<-lm(median_activity ~ group*time_mdl,data=data)
```

However if I look at the full dataset, the fit is no really appealing and I would like to find a function that looks more like the black line I drew by hand:
[image]

My problem is that I have no idea, whether it would now be the best strategy to find a combination of a polynomal with sin/cos or whether I should use some kind of cyclical analysis.

For reference this is the QQ plot of the whole dataset:

[image]

Comment: [Nonparametric regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_regression)?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that. However: `model.np <- npreg(median_activity ~ group+time_mdl,
                    regtype = "ll",
                    bwmethod = "cv.aic",
                    gradients = TRUE,
                   data = data)` improves the R squared only by 2 % for the whole dataset. @Alexis

Comment: I don't see the problem.